# count total records for individual user after groupBy select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql select query that has a groupBy. I want to count all the records after the group by statement for individual user. Is there a way for this directly from mysql ?

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT distinct(tape_no) , user_id, username FROM `audio_history`  group by username , tape_no');
$i=1;
$temp = '';
 while($res = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
  if($temp != $res->username && $temp != ''){
  echo $res->user_id . '---' .$temp  . "$i<br>";
  $i = 0;
  }
 temp = $res->username;
 $count = $i;
 $i++;
 }
```

sql statement

```
SELECT distinct(tape_no) ,
 user_id, username 
FROM `audio_history`  
group by username , tape_no
```

returns

```
tape_no user_id username    
001 790 adam
422 790 adam
903 001 alic
585 005 cooper
356 005 cooper
697 005 cooper
```

I want the output to be returned as

```
 uname    uif  count_for_individual_user
 adam     790     2
 alic     001     1
 cooper   005     3
```

I need to get the simplest way of doing this without using php code , only  by querying. Thanks in advance

Comment: NOTE: **DISTINCT** is _not_ a function. The DISTINCT keyword applies to the entire SELECT list. The parens around the first column in the SELECT list have _no_ effect, they are ignored. If we write **`SELECT DISTINCT(fee), fi`** that makes it "look" like it's a function, but it's not. It's the same as exactly the same thing as **`DISTINCT fee, fi`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a count of the DISTINCT values of tape_no for each user, that is, not including any "duplicate" values of tape_no in the count, add the `DISTINCT` keyword *inside* the `COUNT` aggregate.

```
SELECT username                AS uname
     , user_id                 AS uif 
     , COUNT(1)                AS count_for_individual_user
     , COUNT(DISTINCT tape_no) AS count_distinct_tape_no
  FROM `audio_history`
 GROUP BY username, user_id
```

Given these rows:

```
username user_id tape_no
-------- ------- -------
adam     790     001
adam     790     422
adam     790     422
```

Then the query above will

return **3** for the `COUNT(1)` expression (because there are three rows for `(adam,790)`, and will

return **2** for the `COUNT(DISTINCT tape_no)` expression, because there are only two *distinct* values of `tape_no` for `(adam,790)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username, user_id, count(*)
FROM audio_history
group by username, user_id
```